# js-cookie is not encoding the value the same as php setcookie

Tags: encoding, setcookie, js-cookie

When I create a cookie using this https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

This is my crypt variable contents..

`s192aBszcV7NPrR8KpQbl4u/hkOOmMBzPg2mAhGlZB1/nAcus=0`

Then setting cookie with `js-cookie`..

```
Cookies.set('_siteauth',crypt, {
   expires: 1,
   path: '/'
});
```

This is the js set cookie value...

`s192aBszcV7NPrR8KpQbl4u/hkOOmMBzPg2mAhGlZB1/nAcus=0`

So if I set the same var using php setcookie..

```
setcookie('_siteauth', $crypt, time() + 86400, '/');
```

The value of the cookie is this..

```
s192aBszcV7NPrR8KpQbl4u%2FhkOOmMBzPg2mAhGlZB1%2FnAcus%3D
```

Which is how I expect a cookie value should be. Encoded.

But the documentation for `js-cookie` about encoding says this https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#encoding, which i'm surprised that the value of the set js-cookie is not being encoded at all.

Can anybody shed some light on this please, or I'm missing something with `js-cookie` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [js-cookie documentation](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#encoding) says:

> This project is [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) compliant. All special characters that are not allowed in the cookie-name or cookie-value are encoded with each one's UTF-8 Hex equivalent using [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
>
> [...]
>
> Please note that **the default encoding/decoding strategy is meant to be interoperable [only between cookies that are read/written by js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/pull/200#discussion_r63270778)**. To override the default encoding/decoding strategy you need to use a [converter](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#converters).

(Emphasis mine.)

According to [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1), cookie values can contain any characters from the set `` !#$%&'()*+-./:<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ `` as well as digits (`0-9`) and letters (`a-zA-Z`).

Note that both `/` and `=` are valid characters in cookie values.

Also, no encoding or escaping mechanism is specified:

> The semantics of the cookie-value are not defined by this document.
>
> To maximize compatibility with user agents, servers that wish to
> store arbitrary data in a cookie-value SHOULD encode that data, for
> example, using Base64 [[RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)].

The use of percent-encoding for cookie values is not standardized. It's no surprise that different libraries come up with different encoding schemes for cookie values. In particular, js-cookie wasn't designed to be compatible with any encoding scheme but its own.